# Meaning of "points" in "try saving your points"

Tags: meaning

Kindly explain what does the word "points" mean here?

> *After strangers respond to your initial message, don’t email them every day — or even every week.*
>
> People sometimes interpret a polite reply from a stranger as an offering of friendship. If you’re tempted to reach out too regularly, **try saving your points** in a draft email, and then prune at the end of the month. **Intermittent reinforcement** can be a powerful thing.
>
> [(link)](https://medium.com/@AdamMGrant/if-you-do-this-your-emails-might-be-rude-89bf28656578#.dq991p7bc)

I guess the TFD's [definitions 14 and 15](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/point) can be right, but I am not sure:

14. A specific moment in time: At this point, we are ready to proceed.
15. An objective or purpose to be reached or achieved, or one that is worth reaching or achieving

Also, what did the author mean when he talked about **intermittent reinforcement**?

Answer (score 1):

In this case "your points" are the things you want to say.

If you want to ask about their home, their pets and their hobbies then each of these would be "points".

"Intermittent reinforcement" in this case means going back over these points but not too often or too regularly.

Comment: "Intermittent reinforcement" is specifically a phrase from psychological theory, particularly from the analysis of Pavlov's experiments. It has been found the rewarding a behavior only now and then ("Intermittent reinforcement") fixes it more strongly than rewarding it every time ("consistent reinforcement").